# How to get the a string that is most repeated in a list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a lot of lists like the following:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[1]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[2]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[2]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[3]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[3]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[4]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[4]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[5]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[5]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[6]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/ul[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[7]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/ul[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[8]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[8]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[9]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[9]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[10]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[10]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[11]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/ul[2]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[12]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[12]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[13]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[13]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[14]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[14]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[15]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[15]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[16]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[16]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[17]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[18]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[18]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[19]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[19]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[20]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[20]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[21]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/ul[2]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[22]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[22]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[23]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[23]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[24]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[24]/div[2]/div[4]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[25]/div[2]/h4[1]
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[25]/div[2]/div[4]
```

And I need to extract the portion that is most repeated in each line, which in this case is

**/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li**

What's the best way to do this?

I'm using C#/.net

thanks!

Comment: Your question does not make sense.

Comment: Does the "most repeated" section that you want always start at the beginning of each line?

Comment: yes Jeffrey, always starts at the beginning...

Comment: good question lol, this is a task in a project I'm working...

Comment: Do you mean the most repeated **line**?  The most repeated **portion** *(substring?)* would be `/`

Comment: Why is your answer the correct answer?

Comment: it's actually the most repeated substring (always beginning at the start of each line) in every line, there are some lines that should be discarted that doesn't look like the others

Comment: Wouldn't "/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/" be the portion that is most repeated, since it appears on every line? I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Austin open notepad, paste that sample lines and do a search for that bold string, you'll see that almost all lines has that string

Comment: @John - Since this is programming, you will need to specify exactly what you mean by "almost all lines" and "doesn't look like the others".

Comment: Because of Jeffrey's comment, you need to fully define why your answer is correct.  I suspect once you define that metric coding for it will be easy...

Comment: Do you want the rectangle of the largest area that is flush on the left in which every row is identical over the sorted list?

Comment: @Jeffrey - I would bet that's the answer he's looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is the longest common prefix of all lines. You could obtain it by doing something like that:

```
void Main()
{
    string path = @"D:\tmp\so5670107.txt";
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    string prefix = LongestCommonPrefix(lines);
    Console.WriteLine(prefix);
}

static string LongestCommonPrefix(string a, string b)
{
    int length = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length && i < b.Length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == b[i])
            length++;
        else
            break;
    }
    return a.Substring(0, length);
}

static string LongestCommonPrefix(IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    return strings.Aggregate(LongestCommonPrefix);
}
```

The result is:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[
```

(the expected result you give in the question seems incorrect, since there are lines that don't match it)

I chose a naive approach for the sake of simplicity, but of course there are more efficient ways of finding the longest common prefix between two strings (using a dichotomic search for instance)

Comment: @John, forgot to remove it, sorry... it's an extension method defined in LINQPad, it just prints the variable to the results window. You can use Console.WriteLine instead (I'll update my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a loop.  Assumption is that your list of strings is in a collection called `paths`:

```
var countByPath = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var path in paths)
{
    if (!countByPath.ContainsKey(path))
    {
        countByPath[path] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        countByPath[path]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The longest substring that is repeated in the list? Assumption is that your list of strings is in a collection called `paths`:

```
var currentChoice = "";
foreach (var path in paths)
{
    for (int i = path.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        var candidate = path.Substring(0, i);
        if (i > currentChoice.Length &&
            paths.Count(p => p.StartsWith(candidate)) > 1)
            currentChoice = candidate;
        else
            break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(currentChoice);
```

The result is then

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[10]
```

since it is repeated twice

Answer (score 0):

There is already an algorithm for this. I can't remember what it's called, but if you are interested in language independent implementation. It works in the following way:

1. Read first line
2. Read second line. If second line is the same as first line, than increase counter by one, otherwise keep counter at zero.
3. Carry on reading lines, if three lines are the same (i.e. repeat), than your counter will be 2. If next line is different to the previous three, than decrease counter by 1.

E.g.

String1 - Counter: 0
String1 - Counter: 1 (Store String1 in a variable)
String1 - Counter: 2 (Store String1 in same variable)
String2 - Counter: 1 (Still store String1 in variable)

I hope this makese sense. I did this at uni few years ago. Can't remember mathematician who came up with algorithm, but it's fairly old.